# Scrapy crawler's cookie issue: website language shifted

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to craw a website, which has a language option drop down button on the top, and the default language is English. As shown below.
[image]

While I thought I managed to scrawl the data, then I found almost randomly the output JSON file started to have unicode Arabic characters (I only wanted English version of data).

It seems the spider was lead to Arabic version pages, and the url changed and added a string '/ar/' in between. I then though I can apply some operation to the url to go to English version, but my experiment of the website also shows that as long as I choose any language, the cookie remembers it, and take any page to its translated language version.

```py
    import scrapy
    import re


    class MyExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "my_example"
        start_urls = [
            'https://www.example.org',
        ]


        def parse(self, response):

            for href in response.xpath('//li/a[re:test(@href, "/.*/causes")]/@href'):
                yield response.follow(href, self.parse_case)

            # follow pagination alphabet links
            for href in response.xpath('//li/a[re:test(@href, "/.*/causes/.*letter=A")]/@href'):
                yield response.follow(href, self.parse)


        def parse_case(self, response):

            yield {
                'case_name': response.xpath('//h1/a/text()').extract()[0],
                'causes_names': response.xpath('//h2[text()="Causes"]/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/strong/text()').extract(),
            }
```

Following is the snapshot of the output json file.
[image]

My question is, why does this language shift happen, and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: I don’t think we can answer why a language shift happens without knowing the target website. It is not clear to me if you want to be able to navigate the pages on different languages, or you want to use a single language while crawling the page. You ask if ignoring cookies would work; have you tried?

Comment: @Gallaecio I want to use a single language while cawing the pages. I tried to disable the cookies, but it didn't help. If you mean disable cookie from code, I don't know how.

Comment: Have you check in your web browser if selecting a language in the webpage sets some cookie? If so, you could just manually include such a cookie in your requests with the right language.